# map over list, get item name and content

Tags: r, purrr

```
my_dfs <- list(
  mtcars = mtcars,
  diamonds = diamonds
)
map(.x = my_dfs, ~ print(.x %>% str)) # OK
```

But if I also want to access the name of the item in the list being printed, how can I do that?

```
map(.x = my_dfs, ~ print(.id)) # found a reference to .id in the docs.
Error in print(.id) : object '.id' not found
```

Better yet, I would like both in one call to map, e.g.

```
map(.x = my_dfs, ~ print('About to print str of ' [somehow get list item name here] .x %>% str))
```

Comment: What exactly should be your output?

Comment: Partially related to your question, I think if you're interested in a side effect like printing, `walk` is better suited than `map`

Comment: @tmfmnk desired output would be in the console 'About to print str of mtcars [str of mtcars]' then 'About to print str of diamonds [str of diamonds]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imap()`. The contents will be referenced by `.x`, the name by `.y`.

```r
z <- list(x = "whats in x",
          y = "whats in y")

imap(z, ~ paste(.y, "has contents:", .x))
# $x
# [1] "x has contents: whats in x"
# 
# $y
# [1] "y has contents: whats in y"
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I tried that with my dfs but it printed out a lot more than expected. See e.g. `imap(.x = my_dfs, ~ paste(.y, ' has contents of ', .x %>% glimpse))`. Expected 2 print outs, one for each but instead got several. Is that expected?

Comment: I think that's from using `imap()` instead of `iwalk()`. It is printing in execution, but then also returning the results at the end.

Comment: If I use iwalk only the glimpse(.x) is shown. No reference to the name of the item being printed to console

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure what `glimpse` is doing. Might be worth another question? I am sure somebody will be more helpful than I can be on that one.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, this can be done with `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) paste(y, "has contents:", x), z, names(z))
#$x
#[1] "x has contents: whats in x"

#$y
#[1] "y has contents: whats in y"
```